# Creating a view in Oracle that will show the average salary of each department?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I wish to make a view in Oracle that will show the average salary in each department. The table that I am using is Employee which has **empno**, **salary** and **deptname** fields.

I tried to make it by doing this:

```
create view v_employee 
as select avg(salary),deptname as average_salary from employee 
order by name;
```

which gave me the error:

> not a single group function

so then I tried to group them by doing

```
create view v_employee
as select avg(salary),deptname as average_salary from employee 
group by salary 
order by name
```

which gave me the error:

> not a GROUP BY expression

What can I do to make this view? Thanks

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY deptname`.

Comment: And that column alias fits the first column better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select avg(salary),deptname as average_salary
```

You have requested 2 columns, for the first column there is no label, and  you have relabeled deptname to "average_salary". So you probably really wanted:

```
select deptname, avg(salary) as average_salary
```

To produce an average there has to be some arithmetic performed which takes into account all the salaries across each department, i.e. we "group" the data into one row for each department.

```
select deptname, avg(salary) as average_salary from employee
group by deptname
```

For every column in the select clause, where we have not used an aggregation function like `AVG()`, we must used that same column in the group by clause. If you don't you will get error messages about "not a group by expression".

Ater all that we can add the create view code:

```
create view v_employee as
select deptname, avg(salary) as average_salary from employee
group by deptname
```

BUT, you should never place an `order by` into a view as this is potentially very inefficient. When you use the view is a subsequent query, THEN include an `order by` e.g.

```
select *
from v_employee
where deptname like 's%'
order by average_salary DESC
```

In that example any embedded order inside the view would simply be discarded because what we want now is the highest average first. Also, because we have used a where clause, we only need to order a few rows, not all of them.